# Is my code recursive If I use the break command?

Tags: java, recursion, break, greedy

I'm learning about recursive and Greedy algorithms, this code separate the change needed for a original amount. I tried using a recursive algorithm but the code wasn't working properly until I added the break to avoid further iterations. Is this correct?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        int[] coinSet = {20,10,5,1};
        int N = 214;
        GreedyChange greedyChange = new GreedyChange();
        greedyChange.greedyChange(coinSet,N);
        greedyChange.printChange();
    }
}


public class GreedyChange {
    private final List<Integer> coins = new ArrayList<>();

    public void greedyChange(int[] coinSet, int change) {
        if(change<=0){
            return;
        }
        for (int j : coinSet) {
            if (change - j >= 0) {
                coins.add(j);
                change -= j;
                greedyChange(coinSet, change);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void printChange() {
        System.out.println("The change is being distributed in " + coins.size() + " coins in the following" +
                " way: ");
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < coins.size(); i++) {
            if (i == coins.size() - 1) {
                System.out.print( "$" +coins.get(i));
            } else {
                System.out.print("$" + coins.get(i) + " + ");
            }
            sum += coins.get(i);
        }
        System.out.print(" = $" + sum);
    }

}
```

Comment: Code is recursive if it calls itself.  `greedyChange` definitely contains a call to itself, and because the `break` was added _after_ that self-call,  it is still able to call itself.  So, yes, still recursive.

Comment: A recursive function requires two things: 
1- a base condition that stops the recursion(your first if statement).
2- at least one recursive call to itself (transition).
Your function fulfills these two criteria so yes your function is correct.
You had to add the break because you wanted to stop at the first biggest coin that can be subtracted from the change.

Comment: @VFX - Good explanation. In fact, a third thing is also needed, which is the processing (printing, calculating, storing etc.) of the parameter

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash correct and sometimes the calculation part can be embedded inside the transition, like for example in the factorial recursive function the transition can be written like this:
f(n) = n * f(n-1).

Comment: @VFX - This is yet another good explanation from you. The point I wanted to highlight is that we process the parameters anyway.

Comment: In point of fact you could change the `break` to `return`.